# How to generate an employee id with year of registration in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need to generate an employee id for eg: E13001, the number should be auto incremented, and when the next year comes, it should be E14001(year is 2014).It should again start from 001 for every year. I have tried with `yy` format but the sequence number continues from the previous year. How i suppose to my change the sequence number generation ? help me. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Possibly by querying the database

Comment: Use a composite primary key with the autoincrement as the second column if you're using MyISAM or BDB database engines

Answer (score 0):

Well, the auto-increment on a column in MySQL will not work except for integers. Also it will increment with each field.

To do what you want, you need to separate the id and year in tow  (for the mysql table). So you get a table with id,emp_id(should not be managed by the db, no AUTO-INCREMENT) and year. Then select max(emp_id) where year ='2014', so when adding a new employee you will increment that value. To get the employe id the way you need it you should merge the tow columns into one and dump the first tow chars from the year.

You should know that this then becomes a distributed e_id, and every time you need to work with it you will need to do extra work. But you keep the format you need.

Hope this helps you get an idea of how it can be done.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can try in the following way

```
<?php   

$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","")
or die("no connection");
$db_select=mysql_select_db("test",$connection)
or die("no connection to db");
$query3 = "SELECT * FROM simple";
$result3 = mysqli_query($query3);
$count = mysql_num_rows($result3);
if($count == 0)
{
$year = date('y');
$seq = 1;
$a = sprintf("%04d", $seq);
$emp_id = E.$year.$a;
$query= "INSERT INTO simple (emp_id) VALUES ('$emp_id')";
$result=mysqli_query($query)or die(mysql_error());
}
else
{
    $query2 = "SELECT * FROM simple ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
    $result2 = mysqli_query($query2);
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result2);
    $last_id = $row['emp_id'];
    $rest = substr("$last_id", -4);  
    $insert_id = "$rest" + 1;
    echo $ars = sprintf("%04d", $insert_id);
    $year = date('y');
    $emp_id = E.$year.$ars;
    $query= "INSERT INTO simple (emp_id) VALUES ('$emp_id')";
    $result=mysqli_query($query)or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Hope this code helps you.

Comment: this code is good, but it will not start from 001 once the next year commences. we have to put some condition for year I guess !

Comment: yes need to add condition for year to fit your exact requirement

Comment: Yeah, that is where my confusion starts. How to put the condition. should i put jan 01 00 hrs ?? could u help me ?

Comment: no i think if you get date('y') as 14 it should again start with 001 need to add conditions to check the dates are equal

Comment: So, the year should be checked for each entry ryt ?

Comment: might be but just looking for some other effective solution

Comment: $rs = substr("$last_id", 1, 2) , if $rs = date('y') then have to do the if block code else it should add 1! will it be ok ?

Comment: I think you are heading closer to what you want

Comment: $rs = substr("$last_id", 1, 2) , if $rs = date('y') after this condition fails , '{
$year = date('y');
$seq = 1;
$a = sprintf("%04d", $seq);
$emp_id = E.$year.$a;
$query= "INSERT INTO simple (emp_id) VALUES ('$emp_id')";
$result=mysqli_query($query)or die(mysql_error());
}' (this code should be repeated)

Comment: good idea but have to implement and see whether it works or not